# Success messages accumulating in rails application using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a scenario, where I need to create record using ajax and display a success message.

After successfully creating the record. Since I am using ajax, if I create a record for the first time, the success message appears, and if I create another record, I see two success messages.

My javascript code is:

```
$(".success").append("<div class='alert'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</a>"Successfully created user."</div>");
```

What should I do so that the success messages does not accumulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The append method adds the html you provide as an argument to whatever already exists in the element. I think what you want to use is the html method instead which has the effect of replacing what's already in the element. So try:

```
$(".success").html("<div class='alert'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</a>"Successfully created user."</div>");
```

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. Here's a link to jquery's html API: http://api.jquery.com/html/.

Comment: @sq1020 Thanks for the answer. I did $(".success").empty().append("...") and it worked.